# d3.js has taken long time to load huge csv file

Tags: d3.js

I have loading issue while i have more then 57 MB csv file. It's taking more then 2 mins for loading graph.

I had tried to spite CSV into 4 different CSV. Tried to load all CSV one by one. But it's taking more then 3 mins to load chart. 
This is the sample records for me. We have very huge data like 200 MB file and 230 MB files.

is D3.js is support this much amount of file size?

If yes, How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: D3 doesn't place any restrictions on the amount of data you can process, it depends entirely on your browser. With a dataset of the size you're describing you're unlikely to get good performance though.

Comment: I have tested this chart on mozila, chrome, safari and IE as well. All browser are taking more then 2 mins to loading 57 MB data. If i go with less size of file like 17 MB then it's working well. we don't have issue at that time. But loading issue is generated when i am using more then 57MB csv. I am using ubuntu with latest version of chrome that is also taking same time.